Postfix TLS Anonymous and Untrusted
We use Postfix on a RHEL server to distribute email to our opted-in users each morning.  We recently enabled smtp (outbound) TLS.  The majority of our email is delivered on Trusted TLS Connections.  We have some Anonymous and Untrusted TLS Connections -- less than 1% of the email sent.
Is there anything we should do with respect to the Anonymous and Untrusted TLS Connections?
Thanks, Greg

Since you have no control about the peer than you cannot fix the peer. The only thing you can do is to increase your security level to not allow such connections. This will then likely lead to delivery problems. If these are acceptable to you (better fail than unsafe) you must decide for yourself.
